# VBA pass string as range, type mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to populate a dynamic named range into a msgBox, but getting error of type mismatch on line `Set xRg = xTxt`.

Below is the code:

```
Sub showOfferRange()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xTxt As String
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xStr As String
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xCol As Long

On Error Resume Next
 xTxt = ThisWorkbook.Names("named_range")
Set xRg = xTxt

If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    For xRow = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
        For xCol = 1 To xRg.Columns.Count
            xStr = xStr & xRg.Cells(xRow, xCol).Value & vbTab
        Next
    xStr = xStr & vbCrLf
    Next

MsgBox xStr

End Sub
```

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set a `Range` object to a String variable. Hence the **type** mismatch.

Do this:

`Set rng = Range("named_range") 'since it's a workbook level name anyway`

Comment: Awesome! Worked as expected

Comment: @joell - great. consider marking as answered so others know moving forward.